# Preventing console from taking input while printing in java?

Tags: java, input, printing, console

I'm having trouble with a method I've made. It reads off from a text file, and prints the contents onto the console with a delay, however, while it's printing it can randomly take inputs from the user. Sometimes it intertwines with the contents it's printing. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public static void filePrint(String location) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        
        File flScannedFile = new File(location);
        
        Scanner scFileScanner = new Scanner(flScannedFile);
        
        while (scFileScanner.hasNext()) {
    
            String file = scFileScanner.nextLine();
                        
            System.out.print(file);
            
            Thread.sleep(650);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be asking a way to prevent user from typing in between the process of printing which I suppose is not possible because _Java is platform independent language. Different Operating systems have their own way of accessing console._ I don't think there is a way in JAVA to do that. But the **helpful thing** is that whatever user types in the console, it will shown at last, not in between. And, change your `System.out.print(file);` to `System.out.println(file);` **It's looks better in printing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user on an IDE will always be able to write on the console, I think this is what is happening to you. The fact that there is a long sleep time is what makes you clearly see that. However, even if the user writes anything on the console, it shouldn't affect the global output.

One thing that I want to add, is that you might want to switch the print to println; and also, it would be better to use a try and catch rather than listing all those exceptions on the method name :)